# UUID.fromString causing "invalid long"

Tags: java, uuid

I'm working on a bluetooth application in eclipse and use an UUID to create a Rfcomm socket. However the UUID cause an error, claiming my UUID is an invalid long.

To create my UUID:

```
final UUID APP_ID = UUID.fromString("BEBCC5EO-0519-11E1-8AF7-EA9ECB6F1004");
```

....but that line gives this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "BEBCC5EO"
```

Also tried this with the same result:

```
public String identifier = "BEBCC5EO-0519-11E1-8AF7-EA9ECB6F1004";
final UUID APP_ID = UUID.fromString(identifier);
```

Why does eclipse believe my string is a long? Please help me solve this error. Would be most greatful!

Comment: That's worthy of a bug report to Oracle; the method should raise a more useful exception with a more useful message. You should choose a better programmer's font in your Eclipse editors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"BEBCC5EO" should be "BEBCC5E0"

You had the letter "O" instead of the digit zero.

Answer (score 0):

Letter `O` in `BEBCC5EO` is not a valid hexadecimal number. Hexa numbers are:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F
```

Answer (score 0):

[UUID.fromString](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/UUID.java#UUID.fromString%28java.lang.String%29) actually splits the input string at `-` tokens. Then decode those a separated parts as `Long` values.

In your case you used `BEBCC5EO`. instead of `BEBCC5E0`. Which can't be parsed as `long`.